# String error. java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

sorry for my english. Read file character by character, you need to find a word that is in the file. Everything seems to be fine, but there is an error **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** Most likely it occurs here int endWord = wordToFind.length (); but this error displays what IU needed. If I wordToFind.length () - 1, the error disappears. But then the output is not what I need.

```
private static String wordToFind = "one"; //word what i need find

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    int endWord = wordToFind.length(); //size word, maby this error
    int startWord = 0; 
    String myWord = ""; // this value create word

    char[] barray = new char[1024]; //byte array

    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("t.txt")))){ //read t.txt

        int value;
        while((value = reader.read(barray, 0, barray.length)) != -1) {

            for(int i = 0; i < value; i++){
                //check character
                if(wordToFind.charAt(startWord) == barray[i]){
                    startWord++;

                    if(startWord > endWord){
                        startWord = 0;
                        myWord = "";
                    }else{
                        myWord += barray[i];
                    }

                    if(startWord == endWord){
                        System.out.println(myWord);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Error : "+e);
    }
}
```

> Error : java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of
>   range: 3

Comment: "most likely" is not good enough.  Please tell us where it occurs **with certainty.**  Also, please post the contents of your "t.txt" file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String has (is backed by) a character array which would hold the value of "one" as `value[] = {'o', 'n', 'e'}` internally.

Array index starts with 0 and goes until n-1, so you can query for values from 0 to 2. Now in your code you have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
if(wordToFind.charAt(startWord) == barray[i]){
    startWord++;
    if(startWord > endWord) {
```

Now lets say your for loop iterates from 0 to 5, you will try:

```
i =0//iteration 1
if(wordToFind.charAt(0) == barray[i]){
    startWord++;// is now 1
    if(startWord > endWord) {//1>3 no

i =1//iteration 2
if(wordToFind.charAt(1) == barray[i]){
    startWord++;// is now 2
    if(startWord > endWord) {//2>3 no

i =2 //iteration 3
if(wordToFind.charAt(2) == barray[i]){
    startWord++;// is now 3
    if(startWord > endWord) {//3>3 no

i =3
if(wordToFind.charAt(3) == barray[i]){//see you are accessing charAt(3)
    startWord++;// is now 4
    if(startWord > endWord) {//4>3 yes
```

Now for i as 3, you are trying to access 3rd element from (String) an array which is being used within the String (which doesn't exist) and hence you get exception.

So you should change your condition from

```
if(startWord > endWord) {
```

To:

```
if(startWord >= endWord) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! if i change `if(startWord >= endWord)` then no output

Comment: Remove these lines `if(startWord == endWord){
                        System.out.println(myWord);
                    } ` and add this in existing if condition `if(startWord >= endWord){
   if (startWord == endWord) {
       System.out.println(myWord);
   }
   startWord = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Those kind of error are mostly do by loops. It is telling you that String is too big and can't fit in your array. Or you are trying to read not existing char/string.

Answer (score 0):

`endWord` is the *length* of your word, but `charAt(int)` is zero-based. This means the highest index you can access is length - 1. So if you were to say

```
String str = "abcd";
char ch = str.charAt(str.length());
```

That would throw an exception, because `str.length()` returns 4, while the indices range from 0 to 3.

So in your code, when you check `startWord > endWord`, this should be `startWord >= endWord`. If that check succeeds, then `startWord` can no longer be used as an index and should be reset. As it currently is, the code will run until `startWord` equals `endWord`, which means that it is one too high to use as index and therefore it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Exception was thrown from

```
wordToFind.charAt(startWord)
```

because the startword was equal to wordToFind.length(). If you take a look at the [docs of charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)), you'll see that will throw an excaption.

I have also removed the try catch block, so that you can see where the exception occurred and the whole exception stack trace.

This line will fix the exception:

if(startWord >= endWord) {

I have also modified the logic to print the word we have found, so that it would be in accordance with my modification to fix the exception.

Here's your code fixed:

```
private static String wordToFind = "mi6"; //word what i need find

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    int endWord = wordToFind.length(); //size word, maby this error
    int startWord = 0;
    String myWord = ""; // this value create word
    char[] barray = new char[1024]; //byte array
    System.out.println("searching:"+wordToFind);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/home/bpgergo/Workspace/mi6-REST_API/handover/README.md"))); //read t.txt
    int value;
    while((value = reader.read(barray, 0, barray.length)) != -1) {

        for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            if(wordToFind.charAt(startWord) == barray[i]){
                startWord++;
                myWord += barray[i];
                if(startWord >= endWord) {

                    System.out.println("Bingo:"+myWord);
                    startWord = 0;
                    myWord = "";
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```